# Is it possible to replicate a latex syntax made in overleaf in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am making a presentation in latex (Oxygen Beamer Template) in the online latex editor Overleaf, it is the original template that overleaf is available to modify it, the idea is to be able to implement it in Rmarkdown. So my question is if there is any package in R or trick to be able to capture the result of latex as a presentation in Rmarkdown?
Anyway when I have an advance or discover something I share it in this same way.
Thanks for your time, regards!

Comment: Not sure what you mean about capturing results from Overleaf. Can you make am example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You could try to ask a question at https://topanswers.xyz/tex Loading beamer themes should not be difficult in rmarkdown